How to immediately bounce emails in Postfix that receive the "452-4.2.2 The recipient's inbox is out of storage space" error
When sending out large amounts of emails, there is always a certain number of recipients that don't ever look at their email box, which is full.
In the mail log it looks like this:
"452-4.2.2 The recipient's inbox is out of storage space"
Right now, these emails stay in the Postfix email deferred queue for 5 days before getting bounced.
How do I make Postfix to bounce these emails immediately?
